# Every n times, skip n items and increase n by 1

Tags: javascript

This is probably an odd question since I have a solution (below), but was hoping someone could show me a more succinct or readable way to do this:

I created a loop that outputs the following array:

[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91]

the gaps between numbers get progressively larger:

- `1-0  = 1`
- `3-1  = 2`
- `6-3  = 3`
- `10-6 = 4`
- `...`
- `91-78 = 13`

etc.

I did it by creating two variables, `step` keeps track of the gap size and `count` keeps track of the current 'position' in the gap.  `count` counts down to zero, then  increases `step` by one.

```
var output = [];
var step = 0;
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (count == 0){
    step += 1;
    count = step;
    output.push(i);
  }
  count -= 1;
}
```

Comment: This seems more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - not sure it's a SO question

Comment: nice, didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
var output = [];
var total = 0;

for (var i=1; i < 100; i++) {
    output.push(total);
    total += i;
}
```

The gaps between numbers simply increase by one for each step, so a for loop should be able to track this change.

Comment: Nice, I knew I was overcomplicating it.  Very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip useless iterations. If you want a sequence of 100 numbers, use

```
var output = [];
var step = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  step += i;
  output.push(step);
}
```

If you want the general term,

```
aₙ = ∑ⁿᵢ₌₀ i = n*(n+1)/2
```

So you can also do

```
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  output.push(i * (i+1) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the total helper variable with this solution:

```
var output = [0]

for (var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
  output.push(output[i - 1] + i)
}

console.log(output) // [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91 ]
```

This solution takes into account that the value to add the counter value to is already present at the last position in the array.

A recursive version is also possible:

```
output = (function f(x) {
  return x.length == 14 ? x : f(x.concat([x[x.length - 1] + x.length]))
})([0])

console.log(output); // [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91 ]
```

Here is no additional counter variable is needed. I use `concat` because it returns an array what I need for the recursive call, where `push` returns the new array length. The argument for `concat` is an array with one element with the new value to add.

Try [online](https://repl.it/FBkk)